# Nested forms with multiple table inheritance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms, formtastic, multi-table-inheritance

How do I build a nested form for objects using multiple table inheritance in rails? I am trying to make a nested form to create an object using a model with a has_many relationship to another set of models that feature multi-table inheritance. I am using [formtastic](https://github.com/justinfrench/formtastic%5D) and [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) for the nested form and the [act_as_relation](https://github.com/hzamani/acts_as_relation) gem to implement the multiple table inheritance.

I have the following models:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 acts_as_superclass
 belongs_to :store
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
     acts_as :product, :as => :producible
end

class Pen < ActiveRecord::Base
     acts_as :product, :as => :producible acts_as :product, :as => :producible
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :products
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :all_blank
end'
```

For this example, the only unique attribute that book has compared to other products is an author field. In reality, I have a number of unique attributes for book which is why I chose multi-table inheritance over the more commonplace single table inheritance.

I am trying to create a nested form that allows you to create a new store with products. Here's my form:

```
<%= semantic_form_for @store do |f| %>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :name %>

    <h3>Books/h3>
    <div id='books'>
    <%= f.semantic_fields_for :books do |book| %>
      <%= render 'book_fields', :f => book %>
    <% end %>
          <div class='links'>
      <%= link_to_add_association 'add book', f, :books %>
      </div>

  <% end %>
<%= f.actions :submit %>
<% end %>
```

And the book_fields partial:

```
<div class='nested-fields'>
  <%= f.inputs do %>
    <%= f.input :author %>
    <%= link_to_remove_association "remove book", f %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I get this error:

```
undefined method `new_record?' for nil:NilClass
```

Based on reading the issues on the github page for [act_as_relation](https://github.com/hzamani/acts_as_relation/issues/9), I thought about making the relationship between store and books more explicit:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
 acts_as_superclass
 belongs_to :store
 has_one :book
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :book, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :all_blank
end

class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
     belongs_to :store
     acts_as :product, :as => :producible
end

class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
        has_many :products
        has_many :books, :through => :products
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :all_blank
        accepts_nested_attributes_for :books, :allow_destroy => true, :reject_if => :all_blank
    end
```

Now, I get a silent error. I can create new stores using the form, and cocoon allows me to add new book fields, but when I submit the store gets created but not the child book. When, I go through the `/books/new' route, I can create a new book record that spans (the products and books table) with no problem.

Is there a workaround to this problem? The rest of the code can be found [here](https://github.com/sdee/nested-form-with-multi-table-inheritance).

Comment: Have you checked the params hash to see if the child book attributes is being included correctly?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you could:

- Build the books relation manually on your `stores_controller#new` action

  `@store.books.build`
- Store manually the relation on you `stores_controller#create` action

  `@store.books ...`  (not really confident on how to achieve it)

Keep us posted.

Comment: Based on your idea to do more manually in the controller, I now am trying to use the create_assocation method, but the method does not seem to automatically get attached via metaprogramming.

Comment: I figured it out finally. I will post the solution once I clean it up some and determine the minimum number of changes I needed to make to get it working. I'm awarding you the bounty since your answer was closest to the final solution.Thanks!

Comment: Sorry for not being able to respond to your comments... busy week. Be sure to post the solution and accept it so the question is marked as answered. Glad I could help.

Comment: Dear sutee,

Any chance you could share you approach to this problem? I have the same problem and have been wondering how to solve it for a few days. At the moment we have a form full of ugly hacks, that is only able to Create objects, but I'd like to have a full CRUD controller. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @antonevangelatov I've committed my solution to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20213579/nested-forms-with-multiple-table-inheritance. However, I've found that solving this problem created another problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22369778/rails-nested-form-splitting-child-records-across-multiple-rows. I have not got any answers to that question so I've moved onto other problems for the time being. Let me know if you have any ideas!

Answer (score 1):

You might want to consider creating your own form object.  This is a RailsCast pro video, but here are some of the examples in the ASCIIcast:

```
def new
  @signup_form = SignupForm.new(current_user)
end
```

This signup form can include relations to your other objects, just as you would in your original controller code:

```
class SignupForm
    # Rails 4: include ActiveModel::Model
  extend ActiveModel::Naming
  include ActiveModel::Conversion
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  validates_presence_of :username
  validates_uniqueness_of :username
  validates_format_of :email, with: /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\Z/
  validates_length_of :password, minimum: 6

  def persisted?
    false
  end

    def subscribed
    subscribed_at
  end

  def subscribed=(checkbox)
    subscribed_at = Time.zone.now if checkbox == "1"
  end

  def generate_token
    begin
      self.token = SecureRandom.hex
    end while User.exists?(token: token)
  end
end
```

Here is the link to the RailsCast.  Getting a pro membership might be worth your time.  I have been getting lucky with a membership through www.codeschool.com where you can get 'prizes' when you finish courses:

RailsCast:
http://railscasts.com/episodes/416-form-objects